# How to compare two values in VBA when a value is bound to vbNewLine in Excel or Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, compare

This is about the structure of a calendar and since I already have too many functions built in, I am not allowed to change the block with **vbNewLine** , so I need to find a way to solve the problem at this one point:

A function should compare two values and trigger an action in case of a match.

The value **myArray(i, 2)** ist the Day-Number:

```
Private Sub InitVariables()

intMonth = Me.cboMonth
intYear = Me.cboYear
lngFirstDayOfMonth = CLng(DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, 1))
intFirstWeekday = getFirstWeekday(lngFirstDayOfMonth)
intDaysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(intMonth, intYear)

End Sub

Private Sub InitArray()
Dim i As Integer

ReDim myArray(0 To 41, 0 To 2)

For i = 0 To 41

    myArray(i, 0) = lngFirstDayOfMonth - intFirstWeekday + 1 + i
    If Month(myArray(i, 0)) = intMonth Then
        myArray(i, 1) = True
        myArray(i, 2) = Day(myArray(i, 0))
    Else
        myArray(i, 1) = False
    
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub LoadArray()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFiltered As DAO.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim OrgTime As Date
Dim MyStrTime As String

On Error Resume Next

strsql = "SELECT * from qrytblImVst;"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strsql)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then

        For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

            If myArray(i, 1) Then
                rs.Filter = "[vDate]=" & myArray(i, 0)

                Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset

                Do While (Not rsFiltered.EOF)
                
                    OrgTime = rsFiltered!vZeit
                    MyStrTime = Format(OrgTime, "hh:mm")
                    
                    myArray(i, 2) = myArray(i, 2) & vbNewLine _
                    & "<div><font color=red> " + MyStrTime + "  </div>"

                    End If
                    
                    rsFiltered.MoveNext
                Loop

            End If
        Next i

    End If

    rsFiltered.Close
    rs.Close

Set rsFiltered = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub PrintArray()

'On Error Resume Next

Dim strCtlName As Variant
Dim strCtlName1 As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim lngBlack As Long
Dim lngWhite As Long

lngBlack = RGB(36, 39, 50)
lngWhite = RGB(166, 166, 166)

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    
    strCtlName = "TXT" & CStr(i + 1)
    Controls(strCtlName).Tag = i
    Controls(strCtlName) = ""
    Controls(strCtlName) = myArray(i, 2)

If IsNull(Controls(strCtlName)) Then
Controls(strCtlName).Visible = False
Else
Controls(strCtlName).Visible = True
End If

If CStr(Me.cboMonth) = CStr(Month(Date)) And CStr(Me.cboYear) = CStr(Year(Date)) And Len(myArray(i, 2)) <> 0 Then
    If Split(myArray(i, 2), vbNewLine)(0) = CStr(Day(Date)) Then
         Controls(strCtlName).BorderColor = lngRed
         Controls(strCtlName).BorderWidth = 2
    End If
Else
Controls(strCtlName).BorderColor = lngWhite
Controls(strCtlName).BorderWidth = 1
End If

    strCtlName = "CAL" & CStr(i + 1)
    Controls(strCtlName).Tag = i
    Controls(strCtlName) = ""
    If InStr(myArray(i, 2), "div") Then
    Controls(strCtlName) = Left(myArray(i, 2), 2)
    Else
    Controls(strCtlName) = myArray(i, 2)
    End If

If IsNull(Controls(strCtlName)) Then
Controls(strCtlName).Visible = False
Else
Controls(strCtlName).Visible = True
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This is how the comparison looks:

```
If Left(myArray(i, 2), 2) = CStr(Day(Date)) Then
     Controls(strCtlName).BorderColor = lngRed
     Controls(strCtlName).BorderWidth = 2
End If
```

I always get a FALSE as a result because **vbNewLine** changes the day number value in such a way that there is no match.

To check what is causing the problem I added "//" and it looks like this

```
msgbox Left(myArray(i, 2), 2) & "//"
```

The result is:

```
5
 //
```

How can I solve this problem, for all calendar days? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison is looking at the first two characters of the stored value. When the day number is less than 10, the second character will be `vbNewLine` because the day number is only one digit.

Instead of using `Left` to capture a fixed number of characters, you can use `Split` to capture everything to the left of `vbNewLine`.

```
If Split(myArray(i, 2), vbNewLine)(0) = CStr(Day(Date)) Then
     Controls(strCtlName).BorderColor = lngRed
     Controls(strCtlName).BorderWidth = 2
End If
```

---

`Split` will return Error (9) when `myArray(i,2)` doesn't have a value. You'll need to introduce a check for that case:

```
If Len(myArray(i,2)) <> 0 Then
    If Split(myArray(i, 2), vbNewLine)(0) = CStr(Day(Date)) Then
         Controls(strCtlName).BorderColor = lngRed
         Controls(strCtlName).BorderWidth = 2
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually you are right, split would be the solution but I get: **ERROR(9) index was outside the bounds of the array**???

Comment: That'll happen is some circumstances if you don't account for it. See my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this version does not work either. Day **1** and day **10** are both framed, probably because of the "1". I have also tried this variant, also without success: **If Left((Split(myArray(i, 2), vbNewLine)(0)), 2) = CStr(Day(Date)) then...**

Comment: I can't help you much from here without seeing the full code. My guess is that something outside the comparison isn't working as you'd expect. I recommend using `Debug.Print` and/or breakpoints to find out exactly what's being compared and when to find out why you're getting false positives.